# HttpGet AsyncTask fatal exception #1

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-get

I've seen other people with this problem, but am not clear how to fix it still.  Actually my code worked prior to updating Android to v. 22 from 21.  Hopefully someone out there had a similar experience.  Anyhow here's my code.

```
   @Override
protected JSONArray doInBackground(String...params) {



    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String url = params[0] + "?longitude=" + curr_longitude + "&latitude=" + curr_lat;
HttpGet httpGet =  new HttpGet(url);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {

            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                  builder.append(line);
                }//end while

                   JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(builder.toString());

                 return jsonarray;


            }//end if

else {

           }}catch (Exception e){
               Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" +e.getMessage());
           }//end try catch
           return null;

}//end function
```

And here is the logcat

```
    06-27 20:22:43.808: W/dalvikvm(29761): threadid=23: thread exiting with uncaught   exception (group=0x40da1930)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scheme 'htpp' not registered.
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry.getScheme(SchemeRegistry.java:80)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ProxySelectorRoutePlanner.determineRoute(ProxySelectorRoutePlanner.java:157)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:596)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at com.example.mapmapagain.MainActivity$GetfromServer.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:456)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at com.example.mapmapagain.MainActivity$GetfromServer.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    at                 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    06-27 20:22:43.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29761):    ... 4 more
```

Thank you so much for any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scheme 'htpp' not registered.
```

Seems like `htpp` should instead be `http`. Check your URL.

Comment: lol Wow thanks.  I hope that's the dumbest thing I ever do on here.